# Like button and old html frames

Tags: facebook-like, frames

We have a VERY old frame style web site. Is it possible to pass a link like `"mysite/index.php?page=the-url-of-the-product.html"` as the `og:url` property ?

Can't get it work for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=La Vita È Bella&amp;p[url]=http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/teachers/resources.html&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/images/imageforfacebook.gif&amp;p[summary]=Drawing on Italy’s most famous export – great-tasting, healthy, colourful food – La Vita é Bella brings families together to experience mealtimes the Italian way">
     <img src='../images/share/s-fb.png' />
    </a>
</pre>
```

So...

> The basic approach is you are providing a link to
>   http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100 which is the basic share page
>   (typically this is shown in a popup).

Comment: thanx for your answer Jorge, but may be I was not clear enough : the idea is to use the FB Like button plug-in.